# Agda pattern matching inside type declarations

Tags: pattern-matching, programming-languages, agda

I am learning HoTT with Agda form beginning.
I followed instructions in https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/HoTT-UF-in-Agda-Lecture-Notes/

When I started to type in declaration of dependent sum type induction just like the notes instructed,

```
record Σ { } {X :  ̇ } (Y : X →  ̇ ) :  ⊔  ̇  where
  constructor _,_
  field
    x : X
    y : Y x

pr₁ : {X :  ̇ } {Y : X →  ̇ } → Σ Y → X
pr₁ (x , y) = x

pr₂ : {X :  ̇ } {Y : X →  ̇ } → (z : Σ Y) → Y (pr₁ z)
pr₂ (x , y) = y


Σ-induction : {X :  ̇ } {Y : X →  ̇ } {A : Σ Y →  ̇ }
            → ((x : X) (y : Y x) → A (x , y))
            → ((x , y) : Σ Y) → A (x , y)

Σ-induction g (x , y) = g x y
```

My agda said there's an error with code `→ ((x , y) : Σ Y)`:

```
expected sequence of possibly hidden bound identifiers
```

And when I change my type declaration like:

```
Σ-induction : {X :  ̇ } {Y : X →  ̇ } {A : Σ Y →  ̇ }
            → ((x : X) (y : Y x) → A (x , y))
            → (z : Σ Y) → A (pr₁ z , pr₂ z)

Σ-induction g (x , y) = g x y
```

This version is fine.

So I'm wondering that if the problem is that agda do not support pattern matching inside type declarations.

p.s. I'm using Agda 2.6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to pattern-match on records in telescopes will be available in the (soon) upcoming version Agda 2.6.1.

Cf. the documentation of the development branch: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/telescopes.html#irrefutable-patterns-in-binding-positions